# Usefulness and validity of Alternative definitions of "quantile"

Tags: probability, quantiles, definition, probability-inequalities

According to textbook, the $p\,$th quantile of a random variable $X$ is any real value $x$ satisfying $P(X \geq x)\geq 1-p$ and $P(X \leq x) \geq p$.

Why isn't the alternative definition,
a $p\,$th quantile of a random variable $X$ is any real value $x$ satisfying $P(X \geq x) \leq 1-p$ and $P(X \leq x) \leq p$, a useful or valid definition of the $p\,$th quantile?

Why isn't another alternative definition

a $p\,$th quantile of a random variable $X$ is any real value $x$ satisfying $P(X \geq x) < 1-p$ and $P(X \leq x) < p$, also a useful or valid definition of the $p\,$th quantile?

Comment: Choice of one definition rather than another is a convention and different conventions can be found in different books . The same holds for definitions of cumulative distribution function.

Comment: The problem with your last "alternative definition" is that such an $x$ never exists.  This is a direct consequence of the axiom of total probability, which asserts $$1=\Pr(X\in\mathbb{R})=\Pr(X\ge x\text{ or }X\le x)\le \Pr(X\ge x) + \Pr(X\le x) \lt (1-p) + p = 1,$$ a contradiction.

Comment: See [R documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.1/topics/quantile) on `quantile` for several different definitions, along with formulas and (in some cases) rationales.